# javascript checkbox containers - is there a simpler way to write this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a checkbox check when I click not only the checkbox, but also the container it's in. The problem I faced is that when I checked a checkbox, it fired it twice because it was also clicking the container. I've come up with the following solution that seems to work fine, but I have a feeling there's a simpler way to do this and I'm looking to learn to really why short and compact javascript, so any advice would be helpful :)

http://jsfiddle.net/masedesign/8q5TQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('td.cell input').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('td.cell').click(function(){
        $(this).find('input').click();
    });
});​
```

The `e.stopPropagation()` method prevents the event from bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

just for fun I tried to achieve the same effect without javascript: if you're interested in a pure CSS solution working only on newer browser (it relies on `:checked` pseudoclasses) look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g6Sx7/2/ (but if you're interested I can improve it with a js fallback for old IE)

**Edit**: a fiddle with js fallback: http://jsfiddle.net/g6Sx7/7/ this code should work fine also on IE6 but here the problem is about CSS support (the adjacent sibling operator `+` is not supported on IE6) : the whole effect won't work there, but anyway you cannot have a box shadow in that browser... so I think it's not a great problem.

Comment: This is interesting..looking to support all the way down to IE6. These will be view across roughly 1,000 users per second, so it needs to be rock solid :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not performing any other task when the checkbox is checked i.e. the js that you have written is just for the sake of making the box clickable then i would suggest to take a CSS approach rather then JS.

here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/8q5TQ/6/

Note: this works in IE7/8/9 FF (latest installed in my machine) and Chrome (latest installed in my machine)

Update: (after reading ur comment) i don't have IE 6 (sorry) but tried in quirk's mode and is working fine. Hope this helps :)